# Pad regex-matches with spaces to uniform length

Tags: regex, perl, padding, sublimetext

I am writing a Sublime Text snippet to insert the header to a matlab-function file. For that purpose I have the following lines:

```
% Inputs:
%    ${3/(\b[^ ,]+\b)|([ ,]+)/(?2:    :$1 - Description\n%)/g}
```

Here, `3` refers to the captured user-input string (e.g. `function(${3:inputs})`
The regex is msotly working: Say `inputs` is `in1, input2`. From my expression, I then get:

```
% Inputs:
%    in1 - Description
%    input2 - Description
```

However I would like to make `- Description` align on `-`.

The documentation on ST says the regex is is Perl-style.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: It might be possible if you get all the matches, find the match with the longest 1st capturing group, then reconstruct the result. It is pretty much impossible to do it on the fly.

Comment: By "on the fly" do you mean in a single regex like the one I printed. The problem is, that within the snippet I only have access to 1 regex for processing the input.

Comment: Yes, "on the fly" means that you repeatedly search and replace stuff. Since you don't know anything about future matches, any attempt to align will fail.

Comment: Might it be possible with some recursion and/or nested substitution Voodoo, though?

Comment: I would recommend using `awk` externally because I know it's possible but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: perl has an "e" flag for allowing you to write perl code on the right side. This would allow you to simply store the longest length in some variable and then pad the matches.
I would not be too sure though this is supported in a "perl-style" regex.